# React JS: How to make this delete button work

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple ToDo application written in React. I cannot figure out how to remove the ToDos.

I have two separate files App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import ToDo from './components/ToDo.js';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          todos: [
            { id: 1, description: 'Walk the cat', isCompleted: true },
            { id: 2, description: 'Throw the dishes away', isCompleted: false },
            { id: 3, description: 'Buy new dishes', isCompleted: false}
          ],
          newTodoDescription: ''
        };
        this.deleteTodo = this.deleteTodo.bind(this);
      }

    handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({ newTodoDescription: e.target.value })
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!this.state.newTodoDescription) { return }
      const newTodo = { description: this.state.newTodoDescription, isCompleted: false };
      this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo], newTodoDescription: '' });
    }


    toggleComplete(index) {
      const todos = this.state.todos.slice();
      const todo = todos[index];
      todo.isCompleted = todo.isCompleted ? false : true;
      this.setState({ todos: todos });
    }


    deleteTodo(id) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        items: prevState.items.filter(item => item.id !== id),
      }))
    }


      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={ (e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
              <input type="text"
                value={ this.state.newTodoDescription }
                onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e) }
                />
              <input type="submit" />
            </form>
            <ul>
              { this.state.todos.map( (todo, index) =>
                <ToDo key={ index }
                  description={ todo.description }
                  isCompleted={ todo.isCompleted }
                  toggleComplete={ () => this.toggleComplete(index) }
                  onDelete={ this.deleteTodo }
                   />
              )}

            </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

The second file is ToDo.js

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';

      class ToDo extends Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" checked={ this.props.isCompleted } onChange={ this.props.toggleComplete } />
              <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteTodo(this.props.id)}>Delete</button>
              <span>{ this.props.description }</span>
            </li>
          );
        }
      }

      export default ToDo;
```

When I click on the button I am presented with an error: TypeError: _this2.props.deleteTodo is not a function

How can I get my current code to work?

Comment: It should be `this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your prop is onDelete,
so in your component ToDo.js, you have to call your function like below

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}>Delete</button>
```

as answer to your comment

your state is define like

```
   this.state = {
      todos: [
        { id: 1, description: 'Walk the cat', isCompleted: true },
        { id: 2, description: 'Throw the dishes away', isCompleted: false },
        { id: 3, description: 'Buy new dishes', isCompleted: false}
      ],
      newTodoDescription: ''
    };
```

So, your function deleteTodo should be like

```
deleteTodo(id) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        todos: prevState.todos.filter(item => item.id !== id),
    }))
};
```

Comment: I made the change but now I am getting the following error TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you should use the splice method.

Comment: Please can you [edit] your answer and elaborate it, preferably with an example. Many other people, with wildly varying skill levels, will visit this question in the future and your answer would be much more valuable to those visitors if you could make it clearer.